# Consulta SQL não retorna valor

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde à todos.

Tenho uma dúvida sobre o que poderia estar dando errado em uma consulta no banco de dados na qual uso templates em PHP. Baseado neste projeto: http://raelcunha.com/template/

Tudo bem, implantei o projeto e tudo funciona precisamente, porém, ao criar uma query para consultar as tabelas do BD, ele retorna o que está lá, mas, somente um registro.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY idS DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$tpl->USER_SHOW_TITLE = $row['username'];
$tpl->USER_SHOW_DESC = substr($row['profi_desc'],0,125).'...';
}
```

Já tentei de várias formas, mas, o reusltado é sempre o mesmo! Ele mostra apenas um registro dos 5 que tenho. :(

Comment: Não utilize `Mysql_`, use `PDO` ou `Mysqli_`

Comment: http://rberaldo.com.br/mysql-obsoleto-php/

Comment: Se você executar a `query` no seu gerenciador retorna quantas linhas?

Comment: Ele está apenas adicionando o último não é?

Comment: Se eu executar a query com echo, ele retorna tudo normal, mas, usando o método da class Template, ele retorna somente um @RobertoFagundes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mtei a charada desta CLASS! Já que ela retorna somente um valor, eu posso usar o método addFile da própria class. Ou seja: addFile($str,$directory); Com isso, consigo incluir um arquivo PHP fora da classe que executa a query sem restrições!  Depois, no template HTML, basta criar a variável cujo usou no AddFile.

```
$tpl->addFile('CONTEUDO','site/tpl/html/index.php');
```

no arquivo index.html colocar a variável:

```
{CONTEUDO}
```

E pronto!!

Obrigado a todos pela assistência!

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta o seguinte:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY idS DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
print_r ($row);
}
```

Com isso estamos pedindo para imprimir o conteúdo da array, vier todos os registros é algo no teu while que está errado.

Como todo mundo está falando em PDO, abaixo segue exemplo de seleção usando PDO:

```
$sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY idS DESC");
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $tpl->USER_SHOW_TITLE = $row['username'];
    $tpl->USER_SHOW_DESC = substr($row['profi_desc'],0,125).'...';
}
```

Tua conexão PDO com o banco:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=tua_tabela;host=localhost';
$user = 'usuario_mysql';
$password = 'senha_mysql';

try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Usando somente o print_r ele retornou tudo, mas, o único detalhe é que usando a variável conforme segue na class, ele não retorna todos os resultados. Apenas um. :( Obrigado mesmo assim!

Answer (score 0):

Evite usar o `msql` como o amigo disse, está obsoleto.

Tente desta forma

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY idS DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $i[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($i as $v) {
    $tpl->USER_SHOW_TITLE = $v['username'];
    $tpl->USER_SHOW_DESC = substr($v['profi_desc'],0,125).'...';
}
```

Se não der, verifique se você não está sobrepondo a `variável` e imprimindo só a última em:

```
$tpl->USER_SHOW_TITLE
```

Comment: Como assim "sobrepondo"? Seria então um problema dentro da própria class do projeto que é mostrado no site acima?

Comment: Isso ! Por exemplo: caso seu objeto não está imprimindo, e você imprime após o loop já iria aparecer somente o último. Da forma que passei (criando um array antes de imprimir) não deu certo ?

Comment: Raoni, infelizmente não deu certo amigo. Eu estou tentando de todas as formas, mas, acho que a forma mais viável é simplesmente abandonar este sistema e montar uma própria class. :(

Comment: Robson, nós vamos resolver isso ! Posta fazendo favor a classe e um script para gerar o banco para que eu consiga testar aqui.

Comment: Ela é muito extensão Raoni... :( Eu vejo ela no github: https://github.com/raelgc/template/blob/master/raelgc/view/Template.php Sobre o script de conexão com o BD, acho que isso é o que pediu, certo?

 $sql["host"] = "localhost";
 $sql["user"] = "USER";
 $sql["pass"] = "SENHA";
 $sql["base"] = "BANCO";
 
  $connection = mysql_connect($sql["host"],$sql["user"],$sql["pass"]);
  $select_database = mysql_select_db($sql["base"], $connection);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Assim que conseguir vou dar uma olhada nela... o do banco é o script de criação do banco, com tabelas, etc... consegue por num git tudo que é necessário para testar ?

Comment: Áh sim... Agora entendi. Consigo! Irei tentar montar um aqui para você!

Comment: https://github.com/robsonlivrebr/first-stack/blob/master/startBD.sql

Comment: Robson eu não encontrei esse `USER_SHOW_TITLE` e o `USER_SHOW_DESC` na classe. Mas pensando melhor, você está chamando um método da classe, então se ele imprime algo, você teria que passar um parâmetro, e não seria por `=` e sim entre parênteses, dessa forma: 
`$tpl->USER_SHOW_TITLE($row['username']);` Se não for isso, aí não tenho como te ajudar se não passar um ZIP ou GIT do projeto inteiro, porque não consigo simular aqui, provavelmente por alterações que você fez no original. Ou me passe seu skype que te ajudo remotamente.

Comment: USER_SHOW_TITLE é a variável que terei que colocar no HTML que será substituído pelo valor (=). Ou seja: USER_SHOW_TITLE = "Olá mundo". No HTML, será colocado no HTML a variável {USER_SHOW_TITLE }. A "class" substituirá o {USER_SHOW_TITLE } pelo valor = "Olá mundo".

Comment: A documentação pede para fazê-lo assim. Essa variável USER_SHOW_TITLE é personalizável, logo, podemos mudá-la para "USER_NAME" e colocar um $row['username'] como valor, e retorna o nome do usuário no banco.

Comment: Então, não achei isso na classe... infelizmente é muita coisa pra ler e conseguir simular... aí complica !

Comment: Mais está bem... Eu agradeço pela sua ajuda. Irei continuar fazendo testes... :D Obrigado!

Comment: Tendo um tempo vou simular isso ! Gosto de desafios ! Só me falta tempo ! Rs

Comment: Obrigado Raoni... :D Muito obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda. :D

Comment: Raoni, matei a charada desta CLASS! Já que ela retorna somente um valor, eu posso usar o método addFile da própria class. Ou seja: addFile($str,$directory); Com isso, consigo incluir um arquivo PHP fora da classe que executa a query sem restrições! Em resumo, agora está funcionando. :) Novamente, obrigado por sua atenção!